# how to ignore logs with docker commit

Tags: docker, dockerignore

I use `docker pull ubuntu` to get the ubuntu:latest docker

Once I had deploy some artifacts in this container, and I want to use it to other place, then I used `docker commit ${container_id}`
However I　found that when I use command of `docker commit`, it push all the files, including the application logs.

I've google for some cases, it may use docker file, and set the `.dockerignore` file to ignore those files I don't need. 
But it matters that I've deployed the application with a license, so could I use this container with the only `docker commit` to commit the changes?

Answer (score 1):

`docker commit` will always capture EVERYTHING in the container filesystem.  It's just the way it works.

`.dockerignore` only applies to the `docker build` command.  `docker build` uses a Dockerfile to take an existing image (like ubuntu:latest), run some modification on it, and commit the result.

If you want to build a container for use somewhere else, a Dockerfile is the way to approach it.  You didn't provide much info, so here is a SUPER sparse example...

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD myartifact /src
CMD /src/my_script.sh
```

and then...

```
docker build -t myOrg/myImage .
```

After which you can run the image with

```
docker run myOrg/myImage
```